# Are questions regarding ISPs and Networking allowed on here?

Tags: discussion

Specifically, a question such as:

"How can I determine if my ISP is throttling my network connection?"

I'll clarify the question, further if I can ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question would be a better fit at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), (compare [Webmasters FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) with [SuperUser FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)) however, you may want to review existing questions about [ISP bandwidth throttling](https://superuser.com/search?q=isp%20bandwidth%20throttling&submit=search) to ensure it is not a duplicate before posting there.